# Process.Exited raising immediately after Process.Start

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ms-word, system.diagnostics

I am facing a weird issue with `Process.Exited` event in .NET Framework v4.5.2.

I have a WPF Application which on button click will open a Word document via `Process`. I am subscribing to `Process.Exited` event to know when the Word document is closed so that I can write some status to database.

Here comes the weird behavior. Assume, I have opened any other Word document or simply open a blank document; and tries to open the document from my application via Button click then `Process.Exited` event is triggered as soon as `Process.Start()` is invoked. The sender argument in `Process.Exited` has values as the document that I just opened from application via button click.

Below is sample code snippet:

```
Process p;

private void WordWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   p = new Process();
   p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
   p.Exited += P_Exited;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var pinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   pinfo.FileName = @"C:\docs\Main Doc.docx";

   p.StartInfo = pinfo;
   p.Start();
}

private void P_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
}
```

Does anyone face similar issue before? I have gone through similar thread but no where a solution is defined. I start wondering is this because of the way how MS-Word process is implemented or a glitch in `Process` implementation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: is your process "ProcessStartInfo" finished job? Did you debug it?

Comment: This is just how Word works: when it starts, it checks to see if a Word process is currently running. If it is, it messages it (using some inter-process communication mechanism) and says "Hey, show a new window containing <Main Doc.docx>", and then exits. Try it yourself: open a few Word documents, and see how many `WINWORD.exe` processes you get.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed multiple `winword.exe` while opening word documents.
What puzzles me is when `Process.Exited` is raised, in this specific scenario, the most recent opened document detail is returned.
Besides this, what I observed is when document is opened, `Process.Exited` is raised. Now, when I close _that_ document, `Process.Exited` is not raised since it's already raised during `Process.Start()`.

Comment: I said the opposite of what you thought I said: I said there is **only one** WINWORD.exe process. Not multiple, a single one.

Comment: The `Exited` event is raised **because the process has exited**. That's what the event tells you. Generally, this happens with programs written to activate existing instances instead of letting new ones run. See duplicate.